# Electric field computation with two point-charges and an infinite conducting sheet

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, coulombs-law

Coordinates in this question are in metres:

> An infinitely large conducting metal sheet is located at z=0 (covers the xy plane). Point charge of 20 μC is at (0, 0, 1) and of -10 μC is at (2, 0, 1). What is the magnitude and direction of the electric field at (1,1,2) ?

I am not able to understand the effect that the conductor will have. I understand that the charges in the conductor will be redistributed by the point charges, with charge densities accumulating under the point charges. But will those redistributed charges affect the electric field at (1,1,2) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electric field parallel to the conductor must be zero. This completely determines the field due to the surface charge distribution. Then apply the first Maxwell equation. Differential form is easiest.

However the mirror charge approach achieves the same and is much easier to use. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges.

Comment: To find the surface charge distribution, can I use superposition ? I know what the distributions would be if either the positive or the negative charge were present in isolation. To find the distribution when they are both present, can I simply add their individual contributions ?